# Use awk to sum or average for each unique ID

Tags: awk

Can anyone tell me how to use awk in order to calculate the sum of two individuals columns or the average of one column for each unique ID.

Input

```
chr1    3661532 3661533 0.0 5   0   chr1    3661529 3662079 NM_01011874     
chr1    3661534 3661535 0.2 5   1   chr1    3661529 3662079 NM_01011874     
chr1    3661537 3661538 0.0 5   0   chr1    3661529 3662079 NM_01011874
chr1    3661559 3661560 0.0 6   0   chr1    3661529 3662079 NM_01011874
chr2    4661532 4661533 0.0 8   0   chr1    4661532 4661533 NM_00175642     
chr2    6661534 6661535 0.2 5   2   chr1    6661534 6661535 NM_00175642     
chr2    2661537 2661538 0.0 5   0   chr1    2661537 2661538 NM_00175642
chr2    9661559 9661560 0.0 7   0   chr1    9661559 9661560 NM_00175642
```

Output (sum $5 $6) for each unique ID

```
NM_01011874 21 1 
NM_00175642 25 2
```

or average of $4 for each unique ID

```
NM_01011874 0.0476
NM_00175642 0.08
```

Also, if you could breakdown the components of the solution I would be grateful. I'm a molecular biologist with minimal bioinformatics training.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

sum of columns 5 and 6 per id:

```
awk '{sum5[$10] += $5; sum6[$10] += $6}; END{ for (id in sum5) { print id, sum5[id], sum6[id] } }' < /tmp/input 
NM_00175642 25 2
NM_01011874 21 1
```

Explained: $10 is the id field, $5 and $6 are columns 5 and 6.  We build 2 arrays for summing columns 5 and 6 (which are indexed by strings, so we can use the id field).  Once we've processed all the lines/records, we iterate through the array keys (id strings), and print the value at that array index.

average of column 4 per id:

```
awk '{sum4[$10] += $4; count4[$10]++}; END{ for (id in sum4) { print id, sum4[id]/count4[id] } }' < /tmp/input 
NM_00175642 0.05
NM_01011874 0.05
```

Explained: Very similar to the summing example.  We keep a sum of column 4 per id, and a count of records seen for each id.  At the end, we iterate through the ids and print the sum/count.

I don't do much with awk, I find Perl much better for small scripts.  But [this](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/AWK) looks like a good starting point.  There are links to more pages with example scripts.